# Cordova File Transfer (+ ngcordova): downloading 'success' but doesn't download files on Android (maybe on iOS)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, file-transfer

I am facing a problem with **Cordova File Transfer**.
I want to download a file, everything seems to work fine, **I have a success, but no file is downloaded at all**. I have spent a entire day trying to figure out what's happening, maybe can you help me ?

Here is my code:

**JS**:

```
...
$scope.downloadFile = function () {

    // File for download
    var url = "http://www.digitallanding.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/download-speed-test-630.jpg";

    // Save location
    var targetPath = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + "TestFile.jpg";

    // Trust every host certificate SSL
    var trustHosts = true;

    // Options to send
    var options = {};

    console.log(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory);
    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
      .then(function (result) {
          console.log(result);
      }, function (error) {
          console.error(error);
      }, function (progress) {
          // After
          })
      });
}
...
```

**HTML:**

```
...
<ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-click="downloadFile()">
            <h2 class="icon ion-document"> Test download</h2>
        </ion-item>
</ion-list>
...
```

Here is my success log:

[image: Success log]

Here is what I have:

- Whitelist plugin installed, configured (with CSP) and initialized (v1.2.1)
- File plugin installed (+ ngcordova lib) and initialized (v4.1.1)
- File Transfer plugin installed (+ ngcordova lib) and initialized (v1.5.0)
- Cordova 6.0.0
- HTC One M8 with Android Marshmallow

I tried in config.xml to add:

```
  <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
  <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="sdcard,cache" />
```

Because I thought it was maybe an error of my phone's right, no result.

I also added:

```
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <allow-intent href="*" />
  <access origin="*" />
```

To allow the whitelist to not blocking anything, but doesn't change too.

I would really appreciate some help on this success / error.

Thanks,

Pierre

Comment: your javascript is not standard. It is Angular, so you should post to the ionic forum for help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova file plugin (v 4.1.1) has permission issue with Android Marshmallow. This issue will not allow folders to be created in android filesystem. This issue is fixed now. You may have to pull the latest FileUtils.java from android src folder in file plugin github to make this work. Hope it helps

Comment: how to transfer the file to download folder. because there is no cordova option i can see for android download folder. File is getting downloaded to app folder. Any suggestions.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine Suggest you to check out this working sample - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations which downloads the file from server and writes it into sdcard folder. you can extend the same to store files in download folder.

Comment: How can we extend to download folder. Please have a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41152137/cordova-file-download-to-android-download-folder I hope you can suggest something.